# Android switchcompat disable on text clicking

Tags: android, onclick, click, switchcompat

I have a `SwitchCompat`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some title"/>
```

and i want to prevent clicking on text title.
As i click on text title, the switch is toggled. But i want to do switching only if i am clicking on toggle icon.

Is it possible? Or do i have to create two separate `views` for that: one `TextView` for title and one `SwitchCompat` without text?

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I separated it into 2 views

Answer (score 0):

I don't find an exact solution for this problem, but you can separate TextView and Swich like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YOUR SWITCH TEXT HERE"/>
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And use switch setOnCheckedChangeListener in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too late..

I wasn't able to create a separated textview because we have some accessibility restrictions but I came up with this solution:

I just created a custom component and overridden `onTouchEvent`:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && thumbDrawable.bounds.contains(
            ev.x.toInt(),
            ev.y.toInt()
        )
    ) {
        toggle()
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Add this:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: please add some more description to your answer!

Comment: @Hamad Not that it would have mattered. since using the `android` namespace results in an InflateException every few iterations of the support library.